# Which Linq join will work for my scenario, confused

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a web api project. In database I have two tables of comments and pictures. I want to use join to merge these two tables in such a way  that every picture should have all the comments related to it. Both tables  have picture id. Which join should I use? I need to use linq. Can someone tell me the linq query I should use?

I have tried cross join, in this way

```
var combo = from p in db.picturedetails 
            from c in db.comments
            select new CommentAndPictureDetails
                {
                    IdUser = p.iduser,
                    IdPictures = p.idpictures,
                    Likes = p.likes,
                    NudityLevel = p.nuditylevel,
                    PicTitle = p.picTitle,
                    PicTime = p.pictime,
                    FakesLevel = p.fakeslevel,
                    Comment1 c.comment1,
                    CTime = c.ctime,
                    IdComments = c.idcomments,
                    SpamLevel = c.spamlevel,
                    TargetPictureId = c.targetpictureid
                };
```

But I am getting all the pictures with all the comments so a very big json. So which join should i use?

Comment: Sorry, Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service. What research have you done, or what queries/code have you tried that aren't working as expected?

Comment: you need to use a group

Comment: Steven V i have edited my code to show my research, and problems i am facing.

Comment: I think i need to use group as mentioned by allo_man.

Comment: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-to-DataSets-Grouping-c62703ea Look at Example Simple 3. Try it, if it doesn't work. Post your code

Comment: You say you want all of the pictures with all of the comments at the start, then at the end you say you're getting all of them and it's too much.  So what do you want?  If the information you need is just too much you'll simply have to need less, or deal with the consequences of getting a lot.  No refactor of the query will change that if just sending the required output from the DB is too much.

Comment: The one that is down voting a new student user question, should be ashamed...

Comment: @Servy he is saying that his query with the cross join is giving him Pic1 with Comment1 and Pic1 with Comment2 etc. etc. when Comment5 is supposed to be a comment on Pic3, for instance, and Pic3 is also getting Comment1 and Comment2 etc. That's what he means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for a group join:

```
var query = from p in db.picturedetails
            join c in db.comments
            on p.PictureId equals c.PictureId into comments
            select new
            {
                ID = p.PictureId,
                Comments = comments,
                //...
            };
```

Comment: Can you tell me what should i keep the type of comments in my Data Transfer Object (DTO)

Comment: @Hmmmmmmmmmm Using this code they are a collection of thos objects

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of LINQ is limited at best but I will try to answer what I assume you are asking.

As far as my understanding of your question goes you are wanting the following to work :

> Table1:
>       PictureID
>       PictureName
>
> Table2:
>   PictureID
>   Comments

And the result to have 1 picture with multiple comments. Is this a correct assumption?

If so I do not believe that is possible with 1 single query as the query will return a picture for every comment, the best way would be to find the 1 picture object, then find the multiple comment objects seperately and return them in some fashion to make it appear as one object.

Comment: your assumption is correct, so how should i make one object from those multiple objects?

Comment: Depending on how you want the object to be displayed/used then you could do something of the following, have the picture object and itterate over the comments to add them to a list/array. How are you creating/planning on creating the return object?

Comment: `"I do not believe that is possible with 1 single query"`  That is incorrect.  It most certainly *is* possible using a single query.

Comment: Apologies, I was referring to my fairly limited knowledge of Linq to try and better understand his question. It's difficult when your not able to add comments without 50 rep.